# Modifying Jason Davies' D3 word cloud to create circular word clouds

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, word-cloud

I'm in the process of trying to modify Jason Davies' code to generate word clouds in D3 (available here: https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud) to print the word cloud in a circle shape rather than a rectangle.  I've been trying to modify the `place()` function so that the board and bounds are circular not square but I'm new to Javascript and don't seem to be making much progress, has anyone else tried to achieve circular word clouds with this code?

Comment: Can you post what code you have so far?

Comment: Did you get this to work?